# Comparing series $\ln(2)+\ln(\ln(2)+1)+\ln(\ln(\ln(2)+1)+1)+...$ to $\sum 1/k^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

This is related to my previous question [Does $\ln(1)+\ln(\ln(2)+1)+\ln(\ln(\ln(3)+1)+1)+...$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701132/does-ln1-ln-ln21-ln-ln-ln311-converge). In the answers it is shown that   $$\ln(2)+\ln(\ln(2)+1)+\ln(\ln(\ln(2)+1)+1)+...$$
diverges. In the notation there, this is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n(1)$.

We do however know that the sequence of terms $$\ln(2),\ln(\ln(2)+1),\ln(\ln(\ln(2)+1)+1),... =f^1(1),f^2(1),f^3(1),...$$ converges to $0$. I want to compare this sequence to $1/k^2$ by letting $n_k$ be the least positive integer such that $f^{n_k}(1)<1/k^2$.  Then we get a strictly increasing sequence of integers.  But I notice something about the sequence $n_k-n_{k-1}$ (by simple Python program):

> 1
>   5
>   10
>   14
>   19
>   22
>   26
>   30
>   34
>   38
>   42
>   46
>   50
>   54
>   58
>   62
>   66
>   70
>   74
>   78
>   83
>   86
>   90
>   94
>   98
>   102
>   106
>   110
>   114
>   118
>   122
>   126
>   130
>   134
>   138
>   142
>   146
>   150
>   154
>   158
>   162
>   166
>   170
>   174
>   178
>   182
>   186
>   190
>   194
>   198
>   202
>   206
>   210
>   214
>   218
>   222
>   226
>   230
>   234
>   238
>   242
>   246
>   250
>   254
>   258
>   262
>   266
>   270
>   274
>   278
>   282
>   286
>   290
>   294
>   298
>   302
>   306
>   310
>   314
>   318
>   322
>   326
>   330
>   334
>   338
>   342
>   346
>   350
>   354
>   358
>   362
>   366
>   370
>   375
>   378
>   382
>   386
>   390
>   394
>   398
>   402
>   406
>   410
>   414
>   418
>   422
>   426
>   430
>   434
>   438
>   442
>   446
>   450
>   454
>   458
>   462
>   466
>   470
>   474
>   478
>   482
>   486

The increase of that sequence appears to be linear.  On average, adding $4$ to the previous term gets the next term. So this shows the $n_k$'s are not increasing too rapidly (i.e. $1/k^2$ is not going to $0$ *that much* faster than $f^n(1)$).  Informally, it looks like the "second derivative" of $n_k$ is constant (approx. 4).

Can anyone prove this is the case, or explain why this is happening?  This would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you do the same comparison using $\frac 1k$?

Comment: Since you know it diverges, you'll end up with a result that says the terms must decrease slower than $\frac{1}{k^2}$

Comment: @obscurans Correct, but I want to know how much slower.

Comment: The original question already gave you an answer that *even starting from a constant value* you have that $f^n(1)>C/n$ for some $C$. Now you have $f^n(1)<1/n$. What's left to do?

Comment: @obscurans I am confused.

Comment: You know that $C/n<f^n(1)<1/n$ for sufficiently large $n$. That's your literal complete answer to "how slow do the terms decrease".

Comment: @obscurans but how does this help answer my question about $1/k^2$ and the numbers from the Python program?

Answer (score 1):

From the previous question, you know that $C/n<f^n(1)<1/n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Since $f^n(1)\in\Theta(1/n)$, we know that $n_k\approx k^2$.

Also, note that you specifically are looking at the *difference* $n_k-n_{k+1}\approx k^2-(k+1)^2=-2k-1$.

In short, you took the finite difference of $k^2$, of course you're getting a linear answer. It has nothing to do with $f^n$ itself.

Just try redoing the program with $n'_k$ defined for $1/k^3$ and see for yourself "the third derivative of $n'_k$ is constant" (approx 12).

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "starting from a constant value" $\epsilon$ in the previous answer.  Does that mean $x=\epsilon$? So for me that should be $1$?

Comment: That statement says $f^n(A)>C/n$ for some $C$ for any $A$. You were, at that point, asking for $f^n(n)$.

Comment: Oh right, I see.  And we are sure that $f^n(1)<1/n$?

Comment: You claimed it, not me. Using only $f^n(1)>C/n$ results in $n_k$ is at least $k^2$

Comment: I think maybe $f^n(1)<D/n$ for some constant $D$ anyway...

Comment: Oh I think maybe we have $f^n(1)<2/n$.

Comment: The entire point is, $f^n(1)\approx C/n\Rightarrow n_k\approx k^2$, and your use of $n_k$ reveals nothing other than that already-known fact.

Comment: My program says that is correct

Comment: Ok, sure. You also already happen to have a math proof of this fact. You've learnt nothing new from this coding exercise is all.

Comment: Ok but we do need both inequalities, correct?  I think you should have to replace $<1/n$ with $<2/n$

Comment: What is the math proof of $<2/n$?